# Get Google Search Results Content

Tags: search, google-search, information-retrieval

I want to get or buy google search results content (structured) from Google itself or any other source that can sell google data legally. I want all results about a specific keyword for the recent 6 months for example.

It will be a good turnaround if I can only get the page content as a raw text for this stage.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic reading out / scraping of Google SERP is against Google ToS. From this point of view there is no one who sells such data legally - any seller violates Googles ToS.

Tere are many offers on markt, where you can get SERP data as JSON or full HTML through API access - just google for it.

The way every seller does SERP scraping is always the same - you can do it by your own. Run many proxies with IP addresses of countries, from where you need SERPs, and query Google with a kind of headless browser. Use captcha solving services to get data even if IP should be banned. Multithread your queries to get more data at once. Thats the whole magic.